# Why is this absolutely positioned element not positioning relative to its container?

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I have this simple code to place two `div #container` elements side by side. In each of these there is a child `div #child` which I would like to position relative to its parent (`div #container`).

```
<style>
.container {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.2ex;
}
</style>

<div class="container">a<br/>
    <div class="child">b</div>
</div>
<div class="container">c<br/>
    <div class="child">d</div>
</div>​
```

However, rather than the result I would expect - 'd' is positioned below 'c' but pushed slightly to the right, 'd' is instead positioned over 'b' and slightly to the right. In other words the absolute position has been rendered relative to the page rather than to its containing element.

1. Why is this the case? What have I misunderstood about absolute positioning here?
2. How can I get the behaviour I was expecting?

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JnMvS/9/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned with respect to the edges of their *containing block*, which is defined as the first ancestor that is not `position: static`.

None of the ancestor elements are `position: static`, so it is with respect to the initial position of the viewport.

Set `position: relative` on the `.container` elements if you really want to absolutely position them.

That said, it looks like you would be better off doing this instead:

```
.child {
    margin-left: 0.2ex;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity what does the ex stand for, never seen that before?

Comment: Thanks appreciate that! Not sure I'd want to use a measurement that would change like that for a margin though, but to each their own I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

To position the child relative to its parent, just add `position:relative` to the PARENT'S style - then all children with position:absolute will be absolute relative to the parent.

```
.container {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position:relative;
}
```